# How to use a custom icon angular

Tags: css, angularjs

I have some angular snippet which looks like:

```
<span ng-if="someproperty.x > 53" 
   ng-click="Call_foobar(user.b)"> class="fa fa-envelope-o pointer" 
  <md-tooltip md-direction="bottom">
     Some tooltip
  </span>
```

I have one small icon I would like to use that I downloaded over the web (say `icon.png` stored in the same directory) instead of the icon being used here `class="fa fa-envelope-o pointer"`. How can I embed my icon? I tried using something similar to `ng src =/pathtoimg/` but that does not seem to work. Online examples are more specific to some packages/classes. Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: Use an `img` tag with `src` pointing to the path of the icon you want within the span. Then position it however you want with css.

Comment: This is a CSS question. Use the `content` property of either the [::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) or [::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/)  pseudo-elements. For more information, see [MDN CSS Reference - `content` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content).